# How to make liquid bubbles material like this in blender?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, lighting, blender-osm

[image]

How to make the liquid bubbles like this in blender

Comment: Could you detail what you mean by "to make" ? Is to simulate oil and water ? Is it to mesh a droplet ? Is it to render a droplet already meshed ?

Comment: I mean the material

Comment: It looks like glass, you need to put the Principled BSDF transmission at 1, lower down the roughness?